# How to find the user who is running rsync?

Tags: linux, process, rsync, cron

In Linux, if rsync is already running, how can we identify which user is running it? And what if it is running as cron job, will the cron job user be different?

Answer (score 1):

`ps aux | grep rsync`

The user is the first column. The above command might list itself in the output, so if you get multiple lines, it's not the one that includes `grep`.

If it's a cronjob, it will show up the same with the correct username, unless it was root who set it up to run as a specified user.

Comment: To avoid getting grep included in the output you can do `ps aux | grep [r]sync`